# Having trouble with Entity Framework and relationships

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm having difficulty understanding how to create relationships with the entity framework. (I'm using the `MVC` architecture, and code first migrations )for example, if I have a class

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PIN { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

and I have another class, let's say for example I wish to track employees hours

```
public class EmployeeHours
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ClockIn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ClockOut { get; set; }
    public Employee emplyee { get; set; }
}
```

I'm having a difficult time understanding how I can have these two classes to interact with each other. Like if John Smith's PIN is `1234`, and he enters his PIN into a textbox, how do I successfully add his clock in time and date to the employee hours class?

and if I have a view that looks like this for the employee to enter their PIN

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ClockIn", "Login")) 
{
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.Employee.PIN)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Employee.PIN)<br />

    <button type="submit">Save</button>
}
```

and the `clockIn` controller looks like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ClockIn(string Pin)//employee clocking in
{            
  _context.EmployeeHours.Add();
  _context.SaveChanges();

  return View();
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to store the time and date associated with this employee in the class, so I can go back and see when this employee clocked in. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [Navigation Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships) to Employee, EG:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PIN { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeHours> Hours { get; } = new HashSet<EmployeeHours>();
}
```

Then use it something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ClockIn(string pin)//employee clocking in
{
    var emp = _context.Employees.Where(e => e.Pin == pin).First();
    var hours = new EmployeeHours();
    hours.StartTime = DateTime.Now;
    //...
    emp.Hours.Add(hours);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Okay, so now the problem I get is it says emp is null? I have a employee with the pin 1234 saved in my Employee table, but for some reason whenever I enter 1234 and hit the button, i get the error "object reference not set to an instance of an object." Any advice?